# Is jQuery UI 1.9.2 full compatible with jQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I currently use jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 in website, we're walking through jQuery Migrate 1.1.1 warnings in Chrome's console log and fix whatever we can.

First, I saw this warning in Chrome:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack() jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:40
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42
migrateWarn jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42
jQuery.fn.andSelf jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:321
$.widget._getHandle jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:1273
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:432
$.widget._mouseCapture jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:1086
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:432
$.widget._mouseDown jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:929
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:432
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:891
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
```

And after looked into jquery-1.9.1.js at line 5678 (nice number :)), I saw this:

```
jQuery.fn.andSelf = jQuery.fn.addBack;
```

so it will still work without jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js in production server (others like $.browser will make runtime error).

I also looked into jquery-ui-1.10.2.js and saw that _getHandle is refactored and no longer use andSelf.

My question is, how do I know which jquery-migrate warning must be fixed and which is safe to use (and fix later)? Is "is deprecated" enough?

Thanks,

Comment: Since only the patch number is different, this should be fully compatible. No changes to the public API are made.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**release history**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history) from jQuery UI wiki, jQuery UI version 1.9.2 is fully compatible with jQuery version 1.6+.

Comment: My question is, how do I know which jquery-migrate warning must be fixed and which is safe to use (and fix later)? Is "is deprecated" enough?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery-ui dialog and I see that it uses `$.browser` which is deprecated in jquery 1.9 and I get an error message.

However, I don't get the error with jquery-ui 1.10.3.